# How to hide the cursor in Awesomium

Tags: awesomium

I tried this:

```
<awe:WebControl x:Name="webBrowser" Cursor="None" Source="http://example.com/"/>
```

but the cursor still shows.

I figured that I could alter the CSS of the page by adding the following line:

```
*{
    cursor: none;
}
```

But, is there a solution for when I don't have the access to the actual page that I'm showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ResouceInterceptor and manipulate the page on the fly to insert custom CSS.

EDIT:

The following implementation should do the job. (It assumes there is a text.css file)

```
class ManipulatingResourceInterceptor : IResourceInterceptor
{
    public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        Stream stream = null;

        //do stream manipulation
        if (request.Url.ToString() == "http://your.web.url/test.css")
        {
            WebRequest myRequest;
            myRequest = WebRequest.Create(request.Url);
            Stream webStream = myRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader webStreamReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            string webStreamContent = webStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

            stream = webStream;

            string extraContent = "*{cursor: none;}";

            webStreamContent += extraContent;
            byte[] responseBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(webStreamContent);

            // Initialize unmanaged memory to hold the array.
            int responseSize = Marshal.SizeOf(responseBuffer[0]) * responseBuffer.Length;
            IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(responseSize);
            try
            {
                // Copy the array to unmanaged memory.
                Marshal.Copy(responseBuffer, 0, pointer, responseBuffer.Length);
                return ResourceResponse.Create((uint)responseBuffer.Length, pointer, "text/css");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Data is not owned by the ResourceResponse. A copy is made 
                // of the supplied buffer. We can safely free the unmanaged memory.
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer and posted a sample implementation. You may want to adopt it for your specific case. You could intercept all html file (so those with ending .html/.htm) and insert a style tag with your css in the header because you have all the html as a string and you can manipulate it as you wish.